# Как сделать чтобы полоса прокрутки появилась через 1 секунду после открытия страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, новичку в области вёрстки кодом... Какой код нужен, чтобы полоса прокрутки появилась через 1 секунду после открытия страницы? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

setTimeout(() => {
document.querySelector('.notShow').classList.remove('notShow')
}, 3000)
});
```

```css
.notShow::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  opacity: 0;
}
body {
  min-height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<body class="notShow">

</body>
```

можно без `setTimeout`, если скрипт внизу

Comment: пока не до этого